# Android string resource Website not working

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

Every time i try to read a website from my android resource strings i get an error

```
<string name="API">http://google.com</string>
```

and my java code is

```
String a =  getText(R.string.API).toString()+"search?q=";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **getString(resId)** instead of ***getText()*** maybe it helps.

```
String a =  getString(R.string.API)+"search?q=";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid url, 'http://google.comsearch?q='.

You must add the slash(/) in either xml or java code.

```
<string name="API">http://google.com/</string>
```

or

```
String a =  getText(R.string.API).toString()+"/search?q=";
```